# Power bi and google analytics. How to set up filters for date before getting full data

Tags: powerbi, analytics

How to set up filters for date before getting full data. Right now pbi export all data from day one. Is more than 1.7mil. rows. I reach limit after 1mil and way to use date filter inside pbi is not a option.

So are posible way setdate range parameter (example last 3 month) before export starts?

In adv editor source code:

```
let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #"1*******1" = Source{[Id="1*******1"]}[Data],
    #"UA-1*******1-1" = #"1*******1"{[Id="UA-1*******1-1"]}[Data],
    #"1*******6" = #"UA-1*******1-1"{[Id="1*******6"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"1*******6",
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:eventAction", {"ga:eventAction"}, {"Event Action"}},
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:eventLabel", {"ga:eventLabel"}, {"Event Label"}},
            /*{Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:date", {"ga:date"}, {"Date"}},*/
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Unique Events", "ga:uniqueEvents"}
        })
in
    #"Added Items"
```

```
#"1*******1" = Source{[Id="1*******1"]}[Data],
    #"UA-1*******1-1" = #"1*******1"{[Id="UA-1*******1-1"]}[Data],
    #"1*******6" = #"UA-1*******1-1"{[Id="1*******6"]}[Data],
```

My guess, after source location we need somehow set date range parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is an old question and supposed that you solve it.
I think it may be useful for those who google this question.
After step #"Added Items" replace text (in #"Added Items")
(be aware first in SelectRows(  should be the name of the previous step)
with next

```
#"combinedData" = Table.Combine({

Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each Text.Contains([Month of Year], "2020"))
Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each Text.Contains([Month of Year], "2019"))
})
```

in
combinedData